# Remove then add elements one-by-one at intervals?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbytagname

I'm currently writing a web application that needs all the elements in the `<body>` tag to be added into the page one by one, at regular intervals. The elements first need to be removed from the page, then put in `setTimeout()` functions at regular intervals to add them back in. Here's what I have so far:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var time = 0;
  for (var i = body.children.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var element = body.children[i];  // get element
    body.removeChild(element);  // remove element from page
    window.setTimeout(function() {  // in [time] seconds, add element back into page
      body.appendChild(element);
    }, time);
    time += 5000;  // five seconds between elements going into the page
  }
}
```

For some reason, this only adds in the first two elements, and the rest are ignored. I think it might be an issue with storing `element` in a `setTimeout()` call, but I'm not quite sure. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It does not work because you use a global variable `element`, Every iteration is setting `element = body.children[i];` so it will only be the last iteration's value...

Comment: @epascarello I added the `var` keyword, and that didn't change the effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `i <= 0`, because you are skipping over the last child (the first element when looping backwards).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // BEGIN
    const body = document.body; // No need to call a method
    let time = 0;
    for (let i = body.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      const removed = body.removeChild(body.children[i]); // remove element from page
      window.setTimeout(function() { // in [time] seconds, add element back into page
        body.appendChild(removed);
      }, time);
      time += 1000;  // 1 second between elements being added back
    }
    // END
  }, 1000); // Wait 1 second, then remove all
}
```

```html
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>
<p>Four</p>
<p>Five</p>
```

If you want to loop forwards, change the way you set your duration.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // BEGIN
    const body = document.body; // No need to call a method
    let time = 0;
    for (let i = body.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      const removed = body.removeChild(body.children[i]); // remove element from page
      window.setTimeout(function() { // in [time] seconds, add element back into page
        body.appendChild(removed);
      }, time);
      time = (body.children.length * 1000);  // 1 second between elements being added back
    }
    // END
  }, 1000); // Wait 1 second, then remove all
}
```

```html
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>
<p>Four</p>
<p>Five</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using CSS and the visibility property as well as adding class names to make the changes necessary over time

```js
collection = document.getElementsByClassName("a")
array = Array.from(collection)
array.forEach(ele => {ele.classList.add("Invis")})
array.forEach((element,index) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        element.classList.remove("Invis")
        element.classList.add("Vis")
        console.log("TimeOut")
    },1000*(1+index))
})
```

```css
.Invis {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.Vis {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>svg</title>
        <meta name="description" content="React Temaplte">
        <meta name="keywords" content="React template">
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body class="body">
        <div class="a">Hello1</div>
        <div class="a">Hello2</div>
        <div class="a">Hello3</div>
        <div class="a">Hello4</div>
        <div class="a">Hello5</div>
    </body>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```